# Excel flutter read data by columns

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is it possible to fetch the data existing in a file.xlsx using `Excel` dependency by columns?

I mean for each column that exist in the sheet it should be stored in a list for example.

I have only found how to fetch data by rows using:

```
for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
    for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this by columns?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you learn example? https://pub.dev/packages/excel/example

Comment: So as i can see the way to do this is by fetching it using cell index "A1" "A2"... ?

Comment: I was hopping to find somethings like excel.tables[table].collumns

Answer (score 2):

I think this code from example is you need:

```dart
/// Iterating and changing values to desired type
for (int row = 0; row < sheet.maxRows; row++) {
  sheet.row(row).forEach((cell) {
    var val = cell.value; //  Value stored in the particular cell
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary solution, downside is that you need to get column heading(s) for getting their values, below is the code if it helps you out:

```
Future<List<ExcelSheetData>> getExcelFile(BuildContext context, String name, String email) async {
    FilePickerResult pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
      allowMultiple: false,
    );
    List<ExcelSheetData> excelList = [];
    int nameIndex;
    int emailIndex;

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setAddMembersLoadingTrue();
      var file = pickedFile.paths.single;
      var bytes = await File(file).readAsBytes();
      Excel excel = await compute(parseExcelFile, bytes);
      for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
        for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
          // name variable is for Name of Column Heading for Name
          if (row?.any((element) => element?.value?.toString() == name) ?? false) {
            Data data = row?.firstWhere((element) => element?.value?.toString()?.toLowerCase() == name);
            nameIndex = data.colIndex;
          }
          // email variable is for Name of Column Heading for Email
          if (row?.any((element) => element?.value?.toString() == email) ?? false) {
            Data data = row?.firstWhere((element) => element?.value?.toString()?.toLowerCase() == email);
            emailIndex = data.colIndex;
          }
          if (nameIndex != null && emailIndex != null) {
            if (row[nameIndex]?.value.toString().toLowerCase() != name.toLowerCase() && row[emailIndex]?.value.toString().toLowerCase() != email.toLowerCase())
              excelList.add(
                ExcelSheetData(
                  name: row[nameIndex]?.value.toString(),
                  email: row[emailIndex]?.value.toString(),
                ),
              );
          }
        }
      }
      setAddMembersLoadingFalse();
      return excelList;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320880/read-data-from-excel-sheet-column-wise-in-flutter) if you need more clarification