# Read Data from Excel sheet Column wise in flutter

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, xlsx

I am Using `excel: ^2.0.1` for reading data from my file picked with [File Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker). I am able to Read each cell by

```
void getExcelFile() async {
    FilePickerResult pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
      allowMultiple: false,
    );

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      var file = pickedFile.paths.single;
      var bytes = await File(file).readAsBytes();
      Excel excel = await compute(parseExcelFile, bytes);
      for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
        print(table);
        print(excel.tables[table].maxCols);
        print(excel.tables[table].maxRows);
        Sheet sheetObject = excel[table];
        for (int row = 0; row < sheetObject.maxRows; row++) {
          sheetObject.row(row).forEach((cell) {
            var val = cell.value; //  Value stored in the particular cell
            print("cell value is: " + val.toString());
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but data is row wise, I want to read Data Column Wise
[image: ExcelSheet]

here I want to add each name with its corresponding email into my class, user can add his own excel file and there could be several headings in that file but i just need name and email

```
class ExcelSheetData {
  var name;
  var email;

  ExcelSheetData({this.name, this.email});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find round about for column index of name and email then I was able to get name and email from each row from that particular index, below is the code if it help someone other:

```
Future<List<ExcelSheetData>> getExcelFile(BuildContext context, String name, String email) async {
    FilePickerResult pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
      allowMultiple: false,
    );
    List<ExcelSheetData> excelList = [];
    int nameIndex;
    int emailIndex;

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setAddMembersLoadingTrue();
      var file = pickedFile.paths.single;
      var bytes = await File(file).readAsBytes();
      Excel excel = await compute(parseExcelFile, bytes);
      for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
        for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
          // name variable is for Name of Column Heading for Name
          if (row?.any((element) => element?.value?.toString() == name) ?? false) {
            Data data = row?.firstWhere((element) => element?.value?.toString()?.toLowerCase() == name);
            nameIndex = data.colIndex;
          }
          // email variable is for Name of Column Heading for Email
          if (row?.any((element) => element?.value?.toString() == email) ?? false) {
            Data data = row?.firstWhere((element) => element?.value?.toString()?.toLowerCase() == email);
            emailIndex = data.colIndex;
          }
          if (nameIndex != null && emailIndex != null) {
            if (row[nameIndex]?.value.toString().toLowerCase() != name.toLowerCase() && row[emailIndex]?.value.toString().toLowerCase() != email.toLowerCase())
              excelList.add(
                ExcelSheetData(
                  name: row[nameIndex]?.value.toString(),
                  email: row[emailIndex]?.value.toString(),
                ),
              );
          }
        }
      }
      setAddMembersLoadingFalse();
      return excelList;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: this works ... thanks #Muzammil_Hassan....